# Open XMLHttpRequest's responseText in new window

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

Is there a way to open XMLHttpRequest's responseText as a working webpage in new window?

Details: I am building a chrome extension that looks for changes on websites by making an XMLHttpRequest and comparing responseText from last version (from background.js). After it finds a change, it notifies user through chrome notification. On clicking this notification, I want to open a tab with this exact data (xhttp.response) and original url, **without making any new request to the website**. This is important for this extension to work properly on auction-related sites and during flash sales. Note that I need this application to run in the background, without even taking up the resources that chrome needs for rendering images/fonts (this is why I am not using chrome extension called [Refresh Monkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/refresh-monkey/ljngnafhejmefmijjoedbclkadhacebd?hl=en)). I have tried window.open('data:text/xml,' + xmlhttp.responseText), but it does not seem to do anything at all!

If there is no way to do this, then I will simply use window.open(url) to open the webpage in a new tab. This will load the whole webpage again, is there anyway to make it load faster, because I just loaded this exact url on XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you call [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) to create a new tab with a predefined local html page. In that html page, you could call[`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) to notify background page that it has been created and wants to retrieve responseText, once received response, display it in the page.

Sample code:

Background page:

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'predefined.html' });

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.action === 'getText') {
    sendResponse({text: 'YOUR RESPONSE TEXT HERE'});
  }
});
```

predefined.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="textId"></p>
    <script src="predefined.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

predefined.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'getText'}, function(response) {
    document.getElementById('textId').innerText = response.text;
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! This is almost perfect. Since original *URL* should be intact (so that the "buy" button does work), I kept one tab loaded with target url. This tab is updated when background finds a change, by injecting "document.body.innerHTML.innerText = response.text;". This works as desired (AFAIK). But I think it might be possible to do this without keeping a tab open. I am looking at chrome.webRequest. Thanks so much for the inspiration :)

Comment: "buy" button or "add to cart" button would be there on a website like amazon/ebay. That's why I wrote "working website"

Comment: [continued]...  because the target url should also be same. Also, I tried your method, relative links are not working, any image/css/js does not load either if html has relative url. (browser is trying to find these files chrome-extension://.... url)

Also, edit in my last comment: I wanted to write [document.body.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText; ] and not [document.body.innerHTML.innerText = xhttp.responseText; ]

Comment: @MyUniqueName, seems I totally misunderstood your question. I thought what you want is to open a new tab and display dynamically retrieved data.